# Sum of $x_1^k+x_2^k+\dots+x_n^k$

Tags: summation

I was recently wondering if there is some quicker way to compute $x_1^k+x_2^k+\dots+x_n^k$ for any natural $k$ than just exponentiation and adding one-by-one? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Newton's identities!

Comment: @Ghartal is that really quicker, though? exponentiation can be pretty quick, and there's a lot of cross-product work in the elementary symmetric polynomials.

Comment: Where $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are?

Comment: @Joffan It's not bad!

Comment: Thanks for quick responses. I'll try to implement both and see which method works quicker - I think that one-by-one method can be faster for small $k$. @JackD'Aurizio In my particular application $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are natural numbers smaller than $7$.

Comment: @MateuszDuchalski: then you may also exploit the Chinese remainder theorem together with the techniques based on the companion matrix/symmetric polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a universal algorithm for any $x_1,\ldots ,x_n,k$, but you could use the [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) for fast exponentiation.